# Laravel 5.4 AWS server

Tags: amazon-web-services, laravel-5

I have created a Laravel project in laravel 5.4 and i have made it live using AWS server . Now the issue I face is I have to provide the 777 permission to storage folder very frequently and due to this the site is not working properly. Can anyone help me with this as what can be the issue ? I have already given 777 permission to storage folder but somehow the permission changes and site stops as it cannot write log in log file. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Ideally giving 777 permissions means who have open the access to ANYONE in the world who can access your storage with all Read/Write permissions.

You need to assign permission to your Web server to access the Directories and files which you can do in following way:

www-XXX can be your webserver user

```
sudo chown -R www-xxx:www-xxx /path/to/your/laravel/root/directory
```

Now in order to grant the storage level permissions to your webserver you need to execute the below commands

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache
sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache
```